# Can anyone modify this script, as I want to store the result in excel in the columns but it's split the result

Tags: powershell

```
$servers= Get-Content "Location "
$PatchingTracker="D:\tracker.csv"
foreach($server in $servers)
{
    if(Test-Connection -ComputerName $server)
    {
        $update= Get-HotFix -ComputerName $server -Description *  | out-file $PatchingTracker -Append
        $uptime= Get-WmiObject win32_operatingsystem -ComputerName $server |     select csname, @{LABEL=’LastBootUpTime’ ;EXPRESSION={$_.ConverttoDateTime($_.lastbootuptime)}} | out-file $PatchingTracker -Append
    }
}
```

Comment: build a `[PSCustomObject]` that contains the items you want in the layout you want. then use `Export-Csv` to create a proper CSV file. last, import the CSV into excel. ///// you may want to experiment with using `;` as the delimiter instead of a comma - that seems to make importing into excel a tad easier.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable suggestion, could you provide any example help. How could I implement PSCustomObject.

Comment: please take a look at my Answer for one way to do what i think you want done. [*grin*]

Answer (score 0):

here's one way to do what i think you want. [*grin*]

what it does ...

- sets the constants
- creates a list of systems
  when ready to do this with real data, replace the entire `#region/#endregion` block with a call to grab your computer name list.
- loops thru the list of computer names
- tests to see if the system responds
- IF yes = grabs the wanted info from the target system
- IF no = sets the values to the `$NoResponse` string
- builds a PSCO that has the desired properties
  you will likely want to change this to better fit your situation.
- sends that PSCO out to the `$Results` collection
- displays the result on screen
- saves the result to a CSV for later use [likely to import into excel]

***please note that using `Invoke-Command` instead of a `foreach` loop would be faster since it would run part of the code on the target systems.*** i was too lazy to write that up, tho. [*grin*]

the code ...

```
$PatchReportFile = 'PatchReport_-_{0}.csv' -f (get-date -Format 'yyyy-MM-dd')
$PRDir = $env:TEMP
$FullPRFile = Join-Path -Path $PRDir -ChildPath $PatchReportFile

$NoResponse = '__n/a__'

#region >>> create server name list
# when ready to do this for real ...
#    - remove or comment out the entire "#region/#endregion" block
#    - add a "Get-Content" or other command to grab your computer list
$ServerList = @"
BetterNotBeThere
LocalHost
10.0.0.1
127.0.0.1
$env:COMPUTERNAME
"@ -split [System.Environment]::NewLine
#endregion >>> create server name list


$Results = foreach ($SL_Item in $ServerList)
    {
    if (Test-Connection -ComputerName $SL_Item -Count 2 -Quiet)
        {
        $CIM_OS = Get-CimInstance -ComputerName $SL_Item -ClassName CIM_OperatingSystem
        $LastBootUpTime = $CIM_OS.LastBootUpTime
        $UpTime_Days = [math]::Round(([datetime]::Now - $LastBootUpTime).TotalDays, 2)

        $HotFixId_List = (Get-HotFix -ComputerName $SL_Item).HotFixId -join ', '
        }
        else
        {
        $LastBootUpTime = $NoResponse
        $UpTime_Days = $NoResponse
        $HotFixId_List = $NoResponse
        }

    [PSCustomObject]@{
        ComputerName = $SL_Item
        LastBootUpTime = $LastBootUpTime
        UpTime_Days = $UpTime_Days
        HotFixId_List = $HotFixId_List
        }
    }

# display on screen
$Results

# send to CSV
#    the delimiter is set to ';' so that excel will [hopefully] import it smoothly
$Results |
    Export-Csv -LiteralPath $FullPRFile -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter ';'
```

the output on screen ...

```
ComputerName     LastBootUpTime         UpTime_Days HotFixId_List
------------     --------------         ----------- -------------
BetterNotBeThere __n/a__                __n/a__     __n/a__
LocalHost        2021-05-12 10:15:45 PM 1.38        KB4601554, KB4561600, KB4570334, KB4577266, KB4577586, KB4580325, KB4586864, KB4589212, KB4593175, KB4598481, KB500...
10.0.0.1         __n/a__                __n/a__     __n/a__
127.0.0.1        2021-05-12 10:15:45 PM 1.38        KB4601554, KB4561600, KB4570334, KB4577266, KB4577586, KB4580325, KB4586864, KB4589212, KB4593175, KB4598481, KB500...
[MySysName]      2021-05-12 10:15:45 PM 1.38        KB4601554, KB4561600, KB4570334, KB4577266, KB4577586, KB4580325, KB4586864, KB4589212, KB4593175, KB4598481, KB500...
```

CSV file content ...

```
"ComputerName";"LastBootUpTime";"UpTime_Days";"HotFixId_List"
"BetterNotBeThere";"__n/a__";"__n/a__";"__n/a__"
"LocalHost";"2021-05-12 10:15:45 PM";"1.38";"KB4601554, KB4561600, KB4570334, KB4577266, KB4577586, KB4580325, KB4586864, KB4589212, KB4593175, KB4598481, KB5003173, KB5003242"
"10.0.0.1";"__n/a__";"__n/a__";"__n/a__"
"127.0.0.1";"2021-05-12 10:15:45 PM";"1.38";"KB4601554, KB4561600, KB4570334, KB4577266, KB4577586, KB4580325, KB4586864, KB4589212, KB4593175, KB4598481, KB5003173, KB5003242"
"[MySysName]";"2021-05-12 10:15:45 PM";"1.38";"KB4601554, KB4561600, KB4570334, KB4577266, KB4577586, KB4580325, KB4586864, KB4589212, KB4593175, KB4598481, KB5003173, KB5003242"
```

Comment: About `-Delimiter ';'`. Perhaps it is better to append the `-UseCulture` switch, so Export-Csv will take whatever is the local `[cultureinfo]::CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ListSeparator` on that machine.

Comment: @Theo - the reason i chose to use that specific delimiter is that several folks have told me that excel requires manually loading comma-delimited files, but can gracefully ingest semi-colon-delimited files. if that is true [i cannot test it], then using that explicit delimiter seems useful.

Comment: I did try this out on several occasions (En-Us machines at work vs Nl-Nl machines at home). Excel actually by default uses the delimiter for both writing and opening Csv files as set in:
Windows 10: **Start > Control Panel > Region > Additional Settings > List Separator** and for Windows 7: **Start > Control Panel > Regional and Language Options > Additional Settings > List Separator.**

Comment: @Theo - thank you for the added info! [*grin*] since changing that delimiter would require changing the `-join` character, i think i will leave it as is for now.

Comment: I tried to run your script and put the server list in text files but the result shows 'N/A' and again I tried only with computer name and IP under @ punctuation then it only shows KB numbers.

Comment: @essexlake - have  you been able to run the code i posted and get similar results to the output i posted?

Comment: Hi Lee,I tried but didn't get result as you posted in the email.

Comment: please add a link to PasteBin with the result you got. otherwise there is no way to find out what went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the below script, as it worked as expected but I am only getting a single KB number in excel, else it provides all the details.

```
$servers= Get-Content "#file path of the server list"

foreach($server in $servers)
{
$windowsupdate= Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $servers -ClassName Win32_QuickFixEngineering -Property * | select HotFixID, InstalledBy, InstalledOn
$uptime= Get-WmiObject win32_operatingsystem -ComputerName $servers | select csname, @{LABEL=’LastBootUpTime’ ;EXPRESSION={$_.ConverttoDateTime($_.lastbootuptime)}} 
  
   foreach($update in $windowsupdate)
   {
$CustomObject = New-Object -TypeName psobject
$CustomObject | Add-Member  -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'Server Name' -Value $servers
$CustomObject | Add-Member  -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'HotFix ID' -Value $update.HotFixID
$CustomObject | Add-Member  -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'Installed By' -Value $update.InstalledBy
$CustomObject | Add-Member  -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'Installed On' -Value $update.InstalledOn
$CustomObject | Add-Member  -MemberType NoteProperty -Name ' Reboot Time' -Value  $uptime.LastBootUpTime -PassThru
$CustomObject | Format-Table
$infoColl=$CustomObject 
  }
} 
$infoColl | Export-Csv D:\Patch_Tracker_$((Get-Date).ToString('MM-dd-yyyy')).csv -NoTypeInformation #Export the results in csv file.
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried with the same script once again and What I get is below.

```
Get-CimInstance : The client cannot connect to the destination specified in 
the request. Verify that the service on the destination is running and is 
accepting requests. Consult the logs and documentation for the WS-Management 
service running on the destination, most commonly IIS or WinRM. If the 
destination is the WinRM service, run the following command on the destination 
to analyze and configure the WinRM service: "winrm quickconfig".
At C:\Users\shivam\OneDrive - Essex Lake Group\Script\PatchTracker1.2V.ps1:20 
char:19
+ ...   $CIM_OS = Get-CimInstance -ComputerName $SL_Item -ClassName CIM_Ope ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ConnectionError: (root\cimv2:CIM_OperatingSystem 
   :String) [Get-CimInstance], CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : HRESULT 0x80338012,Microsoft.Management.Infrastr 
   ucture.CimCmdlets.GetCimInstanceCommand
    + PSComputerName        : localhost
 
Cannot find an overload for "op_Subtraction" and the argument count: "2".
At C:\Users\shivam\OneDrive - Essex Lake Group\Script\PatchTracker1.2V.ps1:22 
char:9
+         $UpTime_Days = [math]::Round(([datetime]::Now - $LastBootUpTi ...
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodCountCouldNotFindBest
 

ComputerName LastBootUpTime UpTime_Days                                        
------------ -------------- -----------                                        
localhost                   @{csname=ELGILE0635; LastBootUpTime=5/25/2021 5:...
```

And the excel file doesn't count anything. Even I tried to check manually Cim_Instance command and it works.